# python program to read a string and return another string

Tags: python

Here is a python program where I give a input string dev it should retrun a string php and vice versa. But this is not working properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str = raw_input("enter the string to be printed:")
print(str)
if str == php :
   print("dev")
else :
   print("php")
```

Comment: `if str == 'php':`, you are missing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you the right way to go:

Sample `simple.py` script:

```
s = raw_input("enter the string to be printed:")
words = ('dev','php')
print 'entered: ', s

if s in words:
   print 'got: ', words[~words.index(s)]
```

---

Now, usage:

a) when entering `dev` string:

```
python simple.py 
enter the string to be printed:dev
entered:  dev
got:  php
```

---

b) when entering `php` string:

```
python simple.py 
enter the string to be printed:php
entered:  php
got:  dev
```

---

Enjoy!

Comment: can u demonstarte it with if loop as what i have tried

Comment: @sysadmincrispy, the point is that I've suggested the optimized solution. Your code will throw `NameError: name 'php' is not defined` and it does not look flexible if it should consider only `dev`, `php` values